# Separate Data in CSV file using Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to separate data in a CSV File.

```
Word, Time
Hello, 1 
Hi, 3
```

I want the python script to print Hello and display it for 1 second before printing Hi and displaying it for 3 seconds.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(df.to_string())
```

Please bare with me as I am new. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you provided, you can feed in a csv file via python pandas and then create a dataframe object. Then iterate through the dataframe and print a word from each row. You can specify how long you want the word displayed (in seconds) using `time.sleep()`

```
import time
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['Word'])
    time.sleep(row['Time'])
```

Output:

```
Hello
Hi
```